# The rewind slider does not work on the video when trying to replay via Html5 Django

Tags: python, django, html5-video

I tried to do video hosting on Django and play videos using Html5, but the video cannot be rewound, the problem disappears after the page is reloaded

post.html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.14.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.14.3/video.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  {% for p in post %}
    <h1>{{p.title}}</h1>
    <div>
      <video id='my-video-{{p.id}}' class='video-js' controls preload='none' width='640' height='264'>
        {% if door == "1" %}
          <source src="{{ p.video_door_1.url }}" type="video/mp4">
        {% else %}
          <source src="{{p.video_door_2.url }}" type="video/webm">
        {% endif %}
        <p class='vjs-no-js'>
          Чтобы посмотреть это видео, пожалуйста, включите поддержку JavaScript и обновите свой браузер.
        </p>
      </video>
      <div>
        <button onclick="changeSpeed('my-video-{{p.id}}', 0.5)">0.5x</button>
        <button onclick="changeSpeed('my-video-{{p.id}}', 1)">1x</button>
        <button onclick="changeSpeed('my-video-{{p.id}}', 1.5)">1.5x</button>
        <button onclick="changeSpeed('my-video-{{p.id}}', 2)">2x</button>
        <button onclick="changeSpeed('my-video-{{p.id}}', 5)">5x</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      // Инициализация плеера Video.js для каждого видео
      var player = videojs('my-video-{{p.id}}', {
        // Настройки плеера
      });

      function changeSpeed(playerId, speed) {
        // Получение объекта плеера по его идентификатору
        var targetPlayer = videojs(playerId);
        // Определение и установка новой скорости воспроизведения
        targetPlayer.playbackRate(speed);
      }
    </script>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

def show_post(request, post_slug, door):
post = Avtobus.objects.filter(slug=post_slug)

```
context = {
    'post': post,
    'menu': menu,
    'door': door,
    'title': 'Видео',
}
return render(request, 'main/post.html', context=context)
```